# datatables adding rows from json and using render to create hyeperlinks

Tags: jquery, datatables

I create datatable, then add wows from a json object.

```
$('#tbl1').dataTable({
  "autoWidth": false,
  "info": false,
  "JQueryUI": true,
  "ordering": true,
  "paging": false,
  "scrollY": "470px",
  "scrollX": "1485px",
  "scrollCollapse": true,
  "columnDefs": [{
    className: "LeftNoWrap",
    "targets": [0, 1]
  }, {
    className: "CenterNoWrap",
    "targets": [2, 3]
  }, {
    className: "RightNoWrap",
    "targets": [4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10, 11, 12, 13]
  }, {
    "targets": 0,
    "data": null,
    "render": function(data, type, row) {
      return '<a id="hrefAcct_' + row.WSACCOUNT + '" href="#">' + row.WSACCOUNT + '</a>';
    }
  }]
});
```

My hyperlink says "undefined".

I'm getting confused on the "data": setting and the options in render.  What I want to be able to do is to reference row to pick up other fields, so that when I have built the hyperlinks on various totals, I can be using other fields from the row in the hyperlink if required.

Here's the JSON structure (returned from Oracle hence the capitals in the names)

```
NAME: "XXXX "
WSACCOUNT: "XX011 "
WSAGEPD1: "2015/09"
WSAGEPD2: "2015/08"
WSAGEPD3: "2015/07"
WSAGEPD4: "2015/06"
WSAGEPD5: "2015/05"
WSAGEPD6: "2015/04"
WSCURRENT: 0
WSINDISPUTE: "N"
WSINTERCO: " "
WSOLDER: 0
WSOLDERTHAN2MONTH: 0
WSPD1: -956.31
WSPD2: 0
WSPD3: 0
WSPD4: 0
WSPD5: 0
WSPD6: 0
WSTOTAL: -956.31
```

Comment: try using `row[1]` instead of `row.WSACCOUNT`. 'row' is the full datasource of the table row so you can access it by index

Comment: Still getting undefined.  My JSON object will have 1..n rows too.

Comment: Sorry, I misunderstood.  Yes, the row[0], row[1] works.  I assumed that the [0],[1] related to the row index, not the column index.  Thank you.